# Bongard Problem 2

Tags: pattern, bongard

*Find the rule that is correct on the left side, but not on the right side.* If you don't know about bongard problems you can [click here.](http://www.foundalis.com/res/diss_research.html)

[image: bongard2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wild guess:

> If we imagine virtual liquid pouring from the top of each square for an interval, all those squares on the left will hold liquid, but those on the right will not.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Correct!

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome! Glad to have found it :)